# How to add Token in Header in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

When i run a thread group `Loop Count` with `2` for the first loop it works well but for second iteration it fails because in Header it add two times the Authorization Bearer token

I have created  HTTP Request sampler named as “Login Request" inside of this sampler i added BeanShell PreProcessor’

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + vars.get("Token")));
```

It works well for 1 iteration but in second iteration it fails error shows there are two authorization in header

Comment: Cant you put a condition there checking if the header is already contained in the header manager ?

Comment: Hi @ Yassin Hajaj ... if i am able to put that condition why would i ask the question ?

Comment: Did you explain that you tried that in your question? Do you have a fully reproducible exemple? Maybe you should be nicer to people trying to help

Comment: After a small lookup its totally possible to put a condition there to check. Maybe you should Google for a few minutes before dropping a question onnthe site

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don’t need any Beanshell to do that

Just add a [Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) and put in it :

- Name: Authorization
- Value: Bearer ${Token}

Answer (score 2):

Amend your code to invoke [removeHeaderNamed() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/control/HeaderManager.html#removeHeaderNamed-java.lang.String-) like:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Header;
sampler.getHeaderManager().removeHeaderNamed("Authorization")
sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header("Authorization","Bearer " + vars.get("Token")));
```

this way you will get confidence that each time you're having only one [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header.

Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) mainly because [Groovy has much better performance comparing to Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) so consider migrating on next available opportunity (the same code will work fine)